# Perfect Square in Leetcode

Tags: c++, math, dynamic-programming, perfect-square

I am having trouble understanding one of a Leetcode Problem.

> Given a positive integer n, find the least number of perfect square numbers (for example, 1, 4, 9, 16, ...) which sum to n.
>
> For example, given n = 12, return 3 because 12 = 4 + 4 + 4; given n = 13, return 2 because 13 = 4 + 9.

Solution:

```
int numSquares(int n) {
    static vector<int> dp {0};
    while (dp.size() <= n) {
        int m = dp.size(), squares = INT_MAX;
        for (int i=1; i*i<=m; ++i)
            squares = min(squares, dp[m-i*i] + 1);
        dp.push_back(squares);
    }
    return dp[n];
}
```

I really dont understand what is going on with `min(squares,dp[m-i*i]+1)`.  Can you please explain?

thx.

Comment: What *exactly* don't you understand? Is it `min`? Is it `dp[m-i*i]+1`? Is it the logic, why the author wrote this?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of doing `min` staff inside the for-loop, I really don't see how this solve the problem.

Comment: @randy That comment you've just written should be part of the question. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39031099/edit) accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution, which you have mentioned, is the bottom-up version of the algorithm. In order to understand the algorithm better, I would advice to look at the top-down version of the solution.

Let's look closer at the recurrence relation for the calculation of the minimal amount of the perfect squares, contained inside the number `N`. For given `N` and any arbitrary number `x` (which is the candidate for being considered as the member of the shortest sequence of numbers, whose perfect squares sums-up to `N`):

```
f(N, x) = 0                                 , if N = 0    ;
f(N, x) = min( f(N, x + 1), f(N - x^2, 1) ) , if N >= x^2 ;
f(N, x) = +infinity                         , otherwise   ;

solution(N) = f(N, 1)
```

Now, having in mind the considered recurrence, we can construct the top-down solution (I will implement it in Java):

```
int solve(int n) {
    return solve(n, 1);
}

int solve(int n, int curr) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ((curr * curr) > n) {
        return POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    // if curr belongs to the shortest sequence of numbers, whose perfect squares sums-up to N
    int inclusive = solve(n - (curr * curr), 1) + 1;
    // otherwise:
    int exclusive = solve(n, curr + 1);
    return Math.min(exclusive, inclusive);
}
```

The runtime complexity of the given solution is exponential.

However, we can notice that there are only `[1..n]` possible values of `n` and `[1..sqrt(n)]` values of `curr`. Which, implies, that there are only `n * sqrt(n)` combinations of different values of arguments of the function `solve`. Hence, we can create the memoization table and reduce the complexity of the top-down solution:

```
int solve(int n) {
    // initialization of the memoization table
    int[][] memoized = new int[n + 1][(int) (Math.sqrt(n) + 1)];
    for (int[] row : memoized) {
        Arrays.fill(row, NOT_INITIALIZED);
    }
    return solve(n, 1, memoized);
}

int solve(int n, int curr, int[][] memoized) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ((curr * curr) > n) {
        return POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    if (memoized[n][curr] != NOT_INITIALIZED) {
        // the sub-problem has been already solved
        return memoized[n][curr];
    }

    int exclusive = solve(n, curr + 1, memoized);
    int inclusive = solve(n - (curr * curr), 1, memoized) + 1;
    memoized[n][curr] = Math.min(exclusive, inclusive);

    return memoized[n][curr];
}
```

Given solution has the runtime complexity `O(N * sqrt(N))`.

However, it is possible to reduce the runtime complexity to `O(N)`.

As far as the recurrence relation for `f(N, x)` depends only on `f(N, x + 1)` and `f(N - x^2, 1)` - it means, that the relation can be equivalently transformed to the loop form:

```
f(0) = 0
f(N) = min( f(N - x^2) + 1 ) , across the all x, such that x^2 <= N
```

In this case we have to memoize the `f(N)` only for `N` different values of its argument.
Hence, below presented the `O(N)` top-down solution:

```
int solve_top_down_2(int n) {
    int[] memoized = new int[n + 1];
    Arrays.fill(memoized, NOT_INITIALIZED);
    return solve_top_down_2(n, memoized);
}

int solve_top_down_2(int n, int[] memoized) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (memoized[n] != NOT_INITIALIZED) {
        return memoized[n];
    }

    // if 1 belongs to the shortest sequence of numbers, whose perfect squares sums-up to N
    int result = solve_top_down_2(n - (1 * 1)) + 1;

    for (int curr = 2; (curr * curr) <= n; curr++) {
        // check, whether some other number belongs to the shortest sequence of numbers, whose perfect squares sums-up to N
        result = Math.min(result, solve_top_down_2(n - (curr * curr)) + 1);
    }

    memoized[n] = result;
    return result;
}
```

Finally, the presented top-down solution can be easily transformed to the bottom-up solution:

```
int solve_bottom_up(int n) {
    int[] memoized = new int[n + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        memoized[i] = memoized[i - (1 * 1)] + 1;
        for (int curr = 2; (curr * curr) <= i; curr++) {
            memoized[i] = Math.min(memoized[i], memoized[i - (curr * curr)] + 1);
        }
    }
    return memoized[n];
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I had a hard time with this too. Let's take the example number n=13.

- First thing to observe is that: 1^2 =1, 2^2=4, 3^2=9, 4^2=16

  - So 13 can't be composed of anything greater than
    3^2. Generically speaking, n can only be composed of numbers 1 to sqrt(n)
  - So we are left with some combination of the square of the following numbers: 1, 2, or 3.
- Next thing we want to do is come up with the recursive formula. This took me a long time to understand. But we basically want to dwindle down to work with a smaller n (that's the whole point of recursion). We do that by subtracting our candidate perfect squares from n. For example:

  - If we try 3, then dp(13)=dp(13-3^2)+1=dp(4)+1.
    The +1 is incrementing the count by 1 and is from the the fact that we already took off a perfect square from 13, which was the 3^2. Each +1 is a perfect square that we took off.
  - If we try 2, then dp(13)=13-2^2=dp(9)+1
  - If we try 1, then dp(13)=13-1^2=dp(12)+1

So we are left with comparing which is the smallest out of dp(4), dp(9), and dp(12). Hence the min.

Comment: Thanks a ton for amazing explanation. Cleared every doubt!

Answer (score 0):

The clarification to your confusion lies in the question itself.  The structure `dp` holds the *least number of squares* that sum up to the index position of `dp`.

E.g., `squares` would return `3` when `n=9`, but least possible is `1`, which is what `dp[m- i*i] + 1` would return.